# Local Notification is not coming in iOS app using Phonegap?

Tags: ios, angularjs, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I used the local notification plug in for an Android and iOS application. It worked properly with the Android Application but I faced issues with the IOS application.

When used in iOS application I didn't receive any notifications.

For your reference I am sending a sample code which I have used in my application:

```
window.plugin.notification.local.add({
 id:         i,
 message:    "Hello",
 icon: 'file://img/icon.png',
 sound: '/www/audio/beep.mp3',
 badge:      i,
 json:       JSON.stringify({ test: 123 })
});
```

using plugin: `de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification-sv`

Comment: @halfer does not crashing the app, iOS application I didn't receive any notifications.  It worked properly with the Android Application. Please help.

Comment: @halfer the app is not crashing.only thing is the notifications are not showing!.all other app functions are working fine in ios and in andriod everything is working properly including notification